# error in sending mail from separate thread - asp.net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, email, system.net.mail

I'm working in an application which sends the mail from server. since `smtp.send(msg)` will take some time to communicate with the server. i had made the send code block in separate thread. It worked fine before, but after adding the timer control **timer1**( which was doing some code logic). The mail send was interrupted due to the following error :

> **Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a
>   native frame is on top of the call stack**

**Threading** comes here..

```
void sendMail()
{
ThreadStart sendCreateMail = delegate() { Send(subject); };
Thread threadSendCreateMail = new Thread(sendCreateMail);
sendCreateMail.IsBackground = true;
sendCreateMail.Start();
timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

net.mail code comes here....

```
protected void Send(string subject)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com");
                var credential = (System.Net.NetworkCredential)smtp.Credentials;
                string Username = credential.UserName;
                string password = credential.Password;
                mail.From = new MailAddress(Username);
                mail.To.Add(toMail);
                mail.Subject = "subject";

                mail.Body = "msg body";
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, password);
                smtp.Send(mail);
                }
```

**UPDATE**

The **sendMail** task works in other pages. Here it is a popup so that **timer1** block which i already told is doing a popup close function. There it is stopping the execution of thread. that i can understand (like response.end, response.redirect can't guess what exactly, its a third party tool called `telerik radwindow`!). but how to overcome this.

Comment: what version of c# you are using?

Comment: You can look for better option [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: How are you getting that error? That looks more like something I'd expect when trying to inspect variables in a debugger than an error message that a running program would give.

Comment: the error was shown in logger. application looks normal in runtime, but the mail send operation was not occuring @Chris

Comment: Strange. You have a problem in your logging then. I suspect it failed for some more normal reason (eg couldn't connect to smtp server or something) but that your logging failed to actually record this properly for some reason. My approach would be to fix logging first and then get a real failure reason out of it and work from there.

Comment: no, the problem is not with logging.the mail send task works in other pages. here it is a **popup** so that **timer1** block which i already told is doing a popup close function. There it is stopping the execution of thread. that i can understand (like response.end, response.redirect!). but how to overcome this. @Chris

Comment: @Markben: My point was that your logging is broken because it is giving you a meaningless message. If your logging was working then it would have given you the exception that was thrown and with that the stack trace detailing exactly where it went wrong. If you're not getting that then your logging, in my opinion, is broken.

Comment: As to the problem. If adding the timer is causing your problem then presumably there is some code in that timer that causes the problem. Could it be killing the thread that you have set up to send mail? You haven't shown what code is in that but you have mentioned a close popup function. Is that killing the thread that you started?

Comment: i removed the timer,even now also it is working. But when i remove thread and timer. it works perfectly. BUT i want to achieve it using threads for Response reasons @Chris

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84532/discussion-between-mark-ben-and-chris).

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use in my application

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = your port;
client.Host = your host;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 15000;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(your username, your passowrd);
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(your username, recepient[0], title, message);
for (int a = 1; a < recepient.Count; a++)
    mm.To.Add(recepient[a]);
mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    client.Dispose();
    mm.Dispose();
};
client.SendAsync(mm, null);
```

Comment: can u pls tell me, how it differs from the code i have written.. do sendAsync and dispose makes sense?